# Move command error target is not directory UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am new to unix and I am trying to write a bash that moves all files that ends to `.c` to another folder. When I'm executing command:
`find ~/testfiles -name '*.c' -exec mv -i ~/destination {} +` I got an error: `mv: target  '/home/user/testfiles/dir3/sourcefile1.c' is not a directory.`

The `testfiles` folder includes files and folders.
I am using ubuntu 20.04 if that helps..Thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay it works, but i didn't get it why i had to replay + with \;..if u can explaint it i would appreciate it a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Note for clarity. Linux is not Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `find -exec` the `{}` is replaced by the file/directory found.
The `mv` command used as in your example is trying to move the first argument to the second argument so your arguments are in the wrong order.

This would be correct:

```
[[ -d ~/destination ]] && find ~/testfiles -name '*.c' -exec mv -i '{}' ~/destination \;
```

A slightly more effetive way would be to use `mv`s `-t` (target) option which means that you can use the `+` in `find` (to supply as many arguments to `mv` in one go as possible):

```
[[ -d ~/destination ]] && find ~/testfiles -name '*.c' -exec mv -i -t ~/destination '{}' +
```

I added `[[ -d ~/destination ]] &&` before the `find` command since one common mistake is to move a lot of files to the same destination and if it doesn't exist (or is a *file* and not a directory) it'll create a file named `destination` and overwrite that with all the files making you loose all your files (except the last one moved).

Explanation for the shift from `+` to `\;` in `-exec` taken directly from my `man find` page:

`-exec command ;`

> All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered. The string
> `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, ... The specified command is run once for each matched file. ...

`-exec command {} +`

> This  variant of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built **by appending each selected file name at the end**; The command line is built in much the same way that `xargs` builds its command lines. Only one instance of `{}`  is allowed within the command, ...

Note that the syntax differs and that `{} +` must be at the end (where it's appending files) for the second version.